# How To Create Pull Request From Part Of A Branch?

Tags: git

We have a main, shared branch called "develop" and I've created a branch off of it called "feature." At this point, we've decided that we want to only create a pull request for part of the "feature" branch so that it can go back in to "develop" and easily be reviewed by other teammates. The rest of the "feature" branch will not be thrown away and will need to have its bits merged back into "develop" at some point in the future. How can I accomplish this?

Should I create a new branch off of develop and then use "git checkout" to only pull certain files out of the "feature" branch and commit them to this new branch (that way I can make a pull request for it)? If so, then is there a better strategy for bringing the future bits of "feature" back to develop than to manually remember what has been brought over and what hasn't?

[This blog post was a good reference point.](https://jasonrudolph.com/blog/2009/02/25/git-tip-how-to-merge-specific-files-from-another-branch/)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The separation you want to do, is it like file-based? Some files you want to have on one branch and other on another branch? If so, you don't mind having a single revision created _off_ of develop to split the two groups (say, discarding the previous work on feature branch)

Comment: @eftshift0, I do think file-based separation is what I want at this point. I didn't quite understand your last sentence, but I think you mean that the history of the various commits would not be preserved and would turn into one commit, is that correct? If so, preserving history would be ideal but may involve a lot more work.

Comment: Keeping history would be tricky.

Comment: Why not use [git cherry-pick](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick)? So as you mentioned, create a new branch from develop and then cherry pick the single commits needed. you can also cherry pick a range of commits ... should do the trick!?

Comment: @caramba I think cherry pick would also work. The problem was trying to cut down on work because there have been a lot of commits on the feature branch. This might be what is necessary though.

Comment: Do you want to create a pull request from a part of feature branch which in the initial commits or it is in between?

Comment: Let me explain why it would be tricky to keep history and then separate the files: If you do it like that, in history, for those 2 last revisions that you are creating to separate the files, that means that on each one of those files you are actually deleting files that were on feature branch. If you tried merging then those two branches on develop, the first branch would probably merge OK... but the second one is deleting the files that were added on the previous merge and adding others so you would end up with the files from only one of the branches which is not what you would want, right?

Comment: @RishabhAgarwal The commits are in between.

Comment: @eftshift0 Correct. I think I need to pick between preserving history (cherry pick) and less work (file-based checkout). I need to go through your answer and will comment or mark it as the answer when I understand it all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok... assuming feature branch has n (doesn't matter the number, actually) revisions after it was split from develop:

```
git checkout -b branch1 feature
git reset --soft $( git merge-base HEAD develop ) # go back to the last common revision
# at this point all files changed on develop will be on index
# reset the files that you want on the other branch only keep on index the files you want to keep on branch1
git reset filec filee # will keep filea, fileb and filed on this branch
git commit -m "branch 1 - blah blah"
# there you have your branch1 with changes on filea, fileb and filed
git checkout -b branch2 feature
git reset --soft branch1 # so that we don't need to pick the files for this branch
git commit -m "Branch2 - blah blah" # will commit changes for filec and filee
```

At this point the revisions are one after the other, if you would like to have them separated, run this after the previous ones:

```
git rebase --onto branch1~1 branch1 branch2
```

That will move branch2 into a parallel branch.